# CI won't execute properly for Rails project after switching to selenium

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, gitlab-ci, google-chrome-headless

I'm switching from `capybara-webkit` to the `webdrivers` gem and it's all running fine locally for me, get on my CI on Gitlab I'm getting this error `bin/rails: No such file or directory - --product-version` I've updated my `gitlab-ci.yml` to include the `selenium/standalone-chrome:latest` service yet it's still failing and I can't seem to find anything on the issue. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it's not finding the Chrome binary for some reason... I had this exact error on my new laptop just now, and it went away when I installed Chrome. Is there another route you can take to getting Chrome in place, other than adding the service you mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're answering or asking for clarification. Please edit this into an answer, see [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).